# Embed the latest post from instagram to my website

Tags: html, instagram

I am trying to find a way how to embed and show always the latest instagram post from my instagram profile on my website (e.g.iframe). Is there a way to do it?

I found the way how to show specific post only (not the latest post automatically).

Comment: Have you tried this: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent_self ?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent_self
Get you api by logging into instagram.
Call the api from where you want the image to be displayed